# SAS - Pivot or Transpose for Report Output

Tags: sas, pivot, report, transpose

Below is an example of the data in a SAS Dataset.
I am looking to create a report/transpose (Excel term, Pivot) the data to look like the 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

Could someone assist me on getting started?

Comment: Take a look here: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n01rzqgzs8vq1bn10h1wtx914kyf.htm&locale=en

Comment: Please post your data as text, otherwise we have to provide code that's untested or type out your data.

Comment: Beyond the data issue (text please), this is a request for someone to write code for you, which is not on topic here.  Please attempt to solve your problem, and post the code for that attempt if you have questions about how it works or why it's not working, or post a much more specific question about a particular topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Proc Tabulate:

```
PROC TABULATE DATA=WORK.HAVE;

    VAR amount calculated members;
    CLASS year_month /  ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    CLASS category1 /   ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    CLASS category2 /   ORDER=UNFORMATTED MISSING;
    TABLE /* Row Dimension */
       year_month*
       category1,
    /* Column Dimension */
       category2*(
          amount*
             Sum 
          calculated*
             Sum 
          members*
             Sum);
    ;
RUN;
```

The syntax is always confusing to me.  Try using Enterprise Guide and the "Summary Tables" task to create the code for you!

Comment: Thank you, that looks good; I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Yep! it worked! Now I just need to search for the method that can export the way it looks in the proc transpose to an excel file.  Thinking Excel ODS should be a good start...?  thoughts?